# Is there an equivalent to PowerShell's "Switch" in bash?

Tags: bash, powershell

I was curious as to whether or not there is an equivalent to PowerShell's "Switch" command that lets you maneuver with input instead of using a multitude of "if-statements"

Comment: If only there were such a construct in Python.  Alas.

Answer (score 11):

If you're looking at a variable to determine flow, you want to use a `case` statement.

```
case "$var" in
   val1)
      do_something
      ;;
   val2)
      do_something_else
      ;;
esac
```

If you're looking to interactively get user input, you want to also use a `select` statement.

```
select action in proceed ponder perspire quit; do
    case "$action" in
        proceed)
           go_on_then
           ;;
        ponder)
           have_a_think
           ;;
        perspire)
           exude_salty_secretions
           ;;
        quit)
           break
           ;;
    esac
done
```

Comment: Worth noting that it's matching against glob patterns. For example, if you write `[Qq]uit|exit|go-*)`. It'd match "Quit", "quit", "exit", and anything beginning with "go-" like "go-elsewhere". `default` would be `*)`, which is simply a glob that matches anything.